# How to change color of the selected NavigationRailDestination?

Tags: flutter, dart

A navigation rail can be created easily using the below code:

```dart
NavigationRail(
  extended: true,
  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
  destinations: [
    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: Icon(...),
      label: Text('Dashboard'),
    ),      
  ],
),
```

The above code will make the entire navigation rail blue so how to change the color of the selected navigation rail to white? Unselected ones remain blue and only the selected one gets changed to a different color.

Here is a [dribbble design](https://dribbble.com/shots/9713802-SoftwareCompany-Environment), I want to do something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you should try out this

```
Row(
        children: <Widget>[

          NavigationRail(
            selectedIconTheme: IconThemeData(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            selectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
              color: Color(0xffFCCFA8),
              fontSize: 13,
              letterSpacing: 0.8,
              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
              decorationThickness: 2.0,
            ),
            unselectedLabelTextStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 13,
              letterSpacing: 0.8,
            ),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            destinations: [
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: icon,
                label: Text('Menu 1'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: icon,
                label: Text('Menu 2'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: icon,
                label: Text('Menu 3'),
              ),
            ],
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
              child: Center(
                child: Text('Content of Menu $_selectedIndex'),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Comment: This only changes the icon color and not the entire selected navigation rail. I am also using extended: true so the width is more, label is also always visible. So along with icon and label, I want the entire selected navigation rail to be of different color.

Comment: I edited the code and you find out your desire answer

Comment: You can check the updated question. I have added a design which shows what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

So you want like this

```
  NavigationRail(
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = index;
              });
            },  backgroundColor: Colors.blue,

            labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
            destinations: const <NavigationRailDestination>[
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.white),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.favorite,color: Colors.green),
                label: Text('First'),
                
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.bookmark_border,color: Colors.white),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.book,color: Colors.green),
                label: Text('Second'),
              ),
              NavigationRailDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.star_border,color: Colors.white),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.star,color: Colors.green),
                label: Text('Third'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

You can also change `Text('First',style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),`

Don't try to change `NavigationRail` change only `Icon` or `Text` widgets

The appearance of all of the NavigationRails within an app can be specified with [NavigationRailTheme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRailThemeData-class.html). So you need to create ThemeData and specify everything.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationRailTheme-class.html

**Edit after Screenshot.**
thats not NavigationRail. You asked specifically for NavigationRail Widget, and I answered that. Better question is "How to achive this in flutter" and thats a custom widget. This way you pissoff people trying to help you. You better create new question with that screenshot, and There is no Widget that does that, you have te create, start with a container and a ListView then a container for each ListTile. Check The Flutter Way channel on you tube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LN668OAUrK4 and learn how to create custom layouts

[image]

Comment: This only changes the icon color and not the entire selected navigation rail. I am also using `extended: true` so the width is more, label is also always visible. So along with icon and label, I want the entire selected navigation rail to be of different color.

Comment: like bg color of NavigartionRailDestination?

Comment: Please check the updated question. I have added a design from dribbble.

Comment: I was expecting to achieve that using NavigationRail, do you have any other idea on how can I get that kind of sidebar?

Comment: In the past, I had already created that kind of layout where the selected tile gets white background. But to switch the content on the right with the selected item would require a lot of code and calculations. So I thought NavigationRail does this more easily but looks like background color of selected navigation rail is missing at this point so I guess I will have to continue with my old approach. Perhaps someone will add the background color property in flutter code in future now that Flutter web has reached stable and navigation rail is designed for wide screen devices.

Comment: Yeah, but still when you require that much customization, better to make your own SidebarWidget, so probably you are going to need Custom paint too. As per Navigation rail my answer covers whats possible. Can you mark it as accepted and move on. I suggest create new question how to achieve that sidebar in Flutter and probably someone will send you on right direction